# Upload files in server

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I need to upload a csv file from local directory to tomcat server using actionscript and Flex as frontend. The uploaded file should be queried which i have done in java using csv database driver. 
          Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [FileRefrence](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) on flex side, also check [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thank you for your response.. i tried with the example. I'm not using coldfusion in my application, hence i wrote a jsp file for upload function. It reads the file, but it is not uploading, if I'm wrong i dont know where it gets uploaded.

Comment: this is the jsp file am using... '<%@ page import = "javazoom.upload.*,java.util.*" %>
Upload in progress...
<% 
MultipartFormDataRequest mrequest = new MultipartFormDataRequest(request); 
Hashtable files = mrequest.getFiles(); 
if ( (files != null) || (!files.isEmpty()) ) 
{ 
UploadFile file = (UploadFile) files.get("*.csv"); 
upBean.store(mrequest, "*.csv"); 
String sFileURL = "/home/user/" + file.getFileName(); 
%> 
<% 
}
%>'

Comment: Its Flex sample with Java may it helps http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/file_upload.html

Answer (score 0):

fileReference.upload() will do it

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for this is to use AS3 FTP library.

http://code.google.com/p/fl-ftp/